# Why can't I reassign window.document property?

Tags: javascript

I'm playing with Javascript and discovered that I can't change default value(provided by a browser) of `window.document` object.

```js
window.document = 3;
console.log(window.document);
```

I tried to `console.log(window)` in order to see something like read-only property in `document` object but didn't find anything.

It seems like some kind of magic and I want to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for nice question. Under the hood properties can have a descriptors. And we can easily deal with them. Like here:

```js
const dsc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'document');
console.log(dsc);
```

And if you check the result you will see that document property just doesn't have a setter. That's why you can't re-assign it.

And [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) you can find some more information about descriptors

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you should provide English version of the MDN reference though :)

Comment: @ArtemMalchenko sure :)